# React API not showing the data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, axios

I am not able to retrieve content from API every time I reload my page it shows error, please see the attached image, I wanted to find the weather details using Weather API and right now I am using static latitude and longitude.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { FaRegSun } from "react-icons/fa";
import "./stylesheets/stylesheets.css";

function WeatherApp1() {
  const [weatherData2, setWeatherData2] = useState({});

  const API_endpoint2 = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?`;
  const API_key = `2a63c27d8ba0b0d14c9e5d59f39ee1ba`;

  useEffect(() => {
    async function getSecondObject() {
      const response = await axios.get(
        `${API_endpoint2}lat=28.4360704&lon=77.021184&units=metric&appid=${API_key}`
      );
      setWeatherData2(response.data);
    }
    getSecondObject();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="mainDiv">
      <div className="heading">
        <h1>
          <FaRegSun /> Weather
        </h1>
      </div>
      {weatherData2.current.temp}
    </div>
  );
}

export default WeatherApp1;
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oqr7i.jpg

Comment: No image attached. And are you sure the URL you are giving is correct.

Comment: console the `response` and `weatherData2` what you're getting

Comment: You need to add a callback in the useEffect, so that when the resonse wiill come, you can handle that and corresponding functions after call back, can be called.

Comment: on console.log(response) it is still giving the same error and with console.log(weatherdata1) it is giving empty object @AbbasHussain

Comment: ok I am trying with callback @NaveenChandraTiwari

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you're trying to render `{weatherData2.current.temp}` before the `data` is returned from the `weather API` and that's why your `weatherData2` will be `undefined` while `rendering`.

You can add a `loading state` for checking if the `data` is `rendering` or already `rendered`.

You can try below code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { FaRegSun } from "react-icons/fa";
import "./stylesheets/stylesheets.css";

function WeatherApp1() {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true) // Loading state
  const [weatherData2, setWeatherData2] = useState({});

  const API_endpoint2 = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?`;
  const API_key = `2a63c27d8ba0b0d14c9e5d59f39ee1ba`;

  useEffect(() => {
    async function getSecondObject() {
      const response = await axios.get(
        `${API_endpoint2}lat=28.4360704&lon=77.021184&units=metric&appid=${API_key}`
      );
      setWeatherData2(response.data);
      setLoading(false) // Setting the loading state to false after data is set.
    }
    getSecondObject();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="mainDiv">
      <div className="heading">
        <h1>
          <FaRegSun /> Weather
        </h1>
      </div>
       {/* Checking for loading state before rendering the data */}
      {loading ? (
         <p>Loading...</p>
      ) : (
         weatherData2.current.temp            
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default WeatherApp1;
```

Comment: I have done this earlier it is working for that time but whenever I refresh my page it will give the same error again and all contents from my page gets disappear

Comment: Yes it is working fine but the point is that it is for one value suppose I have multiple values in my json and  then in that case I have to do this for every value I want to implement something like once my whole API is loaded then only it will render the stuff

Comment: Thank you for your help, I still need to work on this part

Comment: I've created what you want so do you want me to add another answer?

Comment: Do you want me to add new answer or edit current one?

Comment: you can go for anyone like the way you want.

Comment: ok I'm editing my current one.